# nginx limit bandwidth per Client/IP

Tags: nginx

I have limit nginx bandwidth to 1mb/s and 1 connection maximum . 
But I dont want "per connection" limit, I need per IP or per file bandwidth limitations .

Is it possible to do it by nginx ? if not what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems nginx doesn't have such feature. one can only limit the speed per connection, and number of connection per ip. thats all i know so far.